# Identify VLAN external switch port MAC and IP destinations for each outgoing port

Tags: networking, port, switch, vlan

We have a VLAN we are trying to debug a timeout issue. We’ve narrowed it down to a few switches in the specific VLAN. We cannot seem to find a resource or tool that will tell us the data we need. We know which ports are coming out of the switches, but we need to understand where each one routes to so we can trace each path to check for the loop issue. **All in all we would like to see the destination Mac Address(es) or IP(s) (or both) for each outgoing port on the switches.** Excuse my question if it doesn’t make full sense. I’m not a network architect by career.

Comment: What is the make and model of the switches? Presumably, they have troubleshooting commands you can issue to them.

Answer (score 2):

In general, many switches support LLDP or CDP to announce themselves on a link. You can e.g. use `show lldp info remote` (HPE) to show which device is connected to each port.

Similarly, you can ask a switch which MAC addresses is has associated to each port (`show mac-address` for HPE).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the MAC addresses of the devices attached to each switch interface, you can look at the MAC address table in the switch. A switch is a transparent, layer-2 device. Switches don't know or care about layer-3, e.g. IP. That allows switches to carry any layer-3 protocol (IPv4, IPX, IPv6, AppleTalk, etc.) in the layer-2 frames.

Switches learn MAC addresses each time a frame comes into a switch interface. The switch will look at the source MAC address of an incoming frame, and it will update its MAC address table with the MAC address and the interface where the frame came into the switch. The switch will then look at the destination MAC address, look it up in the MAC address table, and it will switch the frame to the interface indicated in the MAC address table for that MAC address. If the MAC address is not in the MAC address table, the switch will flood the frame to all the other switch interfaces.

How you look at the MAC address table depends on the switch model and software version. (If the switch is unmanaged, you have no way to see it.) For example, you can see the MAC address table on Cisco switches:

```
show mac-address-table
```

For some Cisco switch software versions:

```
show mac address-table
```

This will display all the MAC addresses seen on each switch interface. If the switch is connected to a hub or a different switch, you may see many MAC addresses associated with a single switch interface. What you should never see is multiple switch interfaces for a single MAC address.